# Can you help me use selenium to click "Go to checkout" button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to do a tutorial and learn Selenium in python however I can't seem to get Selenium to click the "Add To Cart" button using either find_element_by_class or find_element_by_XPATH. The problem is to check if the item is out of stock, and if it is out of stock then refresh the webpage and restart the script. If the item is in stock then it should click "Add To Cart"

I am using:

Python v3.9

Chrome v87

This is the URL I am practising on (you may need to add a test item to the basket to see the button or run the script):

https://www.currys.co.uk/app/basket

And this is my current code for the clicking:

```
# Selenium Tutorial #1

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

import time

# Open Chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Ste1337\Desktop\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")

# Open webpage
driver.get("https://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/tv-and-home-entertainment/televisions/televisions/samsung-ue75tu7020kxxu-75-smart-4k-ultra-hd-hdr-led-tv-10213562-pdt.html")

# Click "Accept All Cookies" or ignore if no pop up
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))
    )
    element.click()
except Exception:
    pass

# Wait 3 seconds
driver.implicitly_wait(3)

# Click "Add to Basket" or refresh page if out of stock
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "email-desktop"))
    )
    time.sleep(5)
    browser.refresh()
except:
    button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.Button__StyledButton-bvTPUF.hZIOeU.Button-jyKNMA.GZkwS")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)

# Wait 3 seconds
driver.implicitly_wait(3)

# Click "Continue to Basket"
button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.Button__StyledButton-bvTPUF.hZIOeU.Button-jyKNMA.sc-fzpjYC.gJohPa")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)

# Wait 3 seconds
driver.implicitly_wait(3)

# Click "Go to checkout"
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("Go to Checkout")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

Comment: At which line are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not able to click because one more pop up appear which hides `Add to bastek` button. You need to close that pop up first in order to click.

Induce `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `element_to_be_clickable()` and following `xpath` option

**Code Block:**

```
driver.get("https://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/tv-and-home-entertainment/televisions/televisions/samsung-ue75tu7020kxxu-75-smart-4k-ultra-hd-hdr-led-tv-10213562-pdt.html")
#Accept cookies
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
try:
    #Handle pop up first
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"gis-cta-awareness-close"))).click()
    #Click on Add to basket
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@id='product-actions']//button[contains(.,'Add to basket')]"))).click()

except:
    print("element not found")
```